# Cloning an instance and chaining a method call, possible?

Tags: php, object, clone, chaining

Is possible to `clone` an instance calling a method on it with chaining? This gives me a **syntax error**:

```
/**
 * Parse an object containing (eventually) "duration" property or "year" (and
 * eventually) "month" properties.
 *
 * @return array Array containing start date and end date DateTime objects.
 */
public function parseTimeArgs($args)
{
    $now = new DateTime();

    if(isset($args->duration) && $duration = new DateInterval($args->duration))
        return array((clone $now)->sub($duration), $now);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible. You could use a "factory" method instead:

```
public function parseTimeArgs($args)
{
    $now = new DateTime();

    if(isset($args->duration) && $duration = new DateInterval($args->duration))
        return array($this->clone($now)->sub($duration), $now);
}

public function clone($object)
{
    return clone $object;
}
```

Side note: Using the `new` operator is currently not possible this way either. In the upcoming PHP 5.4 release this will be possible for `new` as follows:

```
$a = (new a())->doStuff()->foMoreStuff();
```

Clone however is not supported here.

Answer (score -1):

```
public function parseTimeArgs($args)
{
    $now = new DateTime();
    $nowClone = clone $now;

    if(isset($args->duration) && $duration = new DateInterval($args->duration))
        return array($nowClone->sub($duration), $now);
}
```

Comment: Yes it's not hard to understand that is the right way, but i'm talking about chaining: `(clone $now)->method()`.